# making HTTP request upon class initialization

Tags: python

New to programming, so may be a stupid question. If so, apologies.

I'm writing a class in Python that on initialization makes  a get request to an API for a rather large amount of data:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, params):
        self.params = json.dumps(params)
        self.r = requests.get(api, data=self.params).json()
```

After initialization, there are a bunch of methods — `bar` and `baz` — that are all meant, in my ideal world, to perform different operations on the the JSON that is fetched upon initialization.

When I instantiate the class and call the methods in succession, I do something like this:

```
test = Foo()
test.bar()
test.baz()
```

My naive understanding is that `test.bar()` and `test.baz()` are performing operations on the **same** JSON fetched upon instantiation of `test` and are **not** making their own API calls. Obviously, the whole thing would be much slower if `test.bar()` and `test.baz()` are each making their own requests. Is my understanding correct? Or are `test.bar()` and `test.baz()` fetching their own copies of the JSON data?

Comment: Never be afraid to ask questions; just make sure to state your goals and objectives clearly, and, most importantly, what you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It entirely depends on the content of the `bar` and `baz` functions.  They **could** call `requests.get` if that's how you write them.

If you're wondering whether or not the `__init__` function is called when you call `test.bar()`, the answer is no, it is not.  `__init__` is only called when you instantiate a `Foo` object.

Answer (score 1):

No, it only happens once on instantiation. Use [sys.settrace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) to watch and be sure.